# "special invitation" to careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I just got a "special invitation" in my inbox to post a professional profile on SO careers 2.0.  This invitation is said to expire in 15 days.  I have always understood that it was free to post a profile on careers 2.0.  Is there really a missed opportunity after the 15-day expiration date or is SO resorting to pressured salesmanship tactics to encourage users to post profiles?

Comment: I got an email on 09 March 2011 with 14 day expiry and didn't sign up until just recently (i.e. a year later). Thought I might need to request a new invite but the code was still valid.

Comment: "special" means you get a kiss from Jeff

Comment: I've just used my invitation from 1 Sept 11 to join...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* free to join, but it's still [invitation-only](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one):

> ### How do I get one?
>
> Stack Overflow profiles are invitation-only, either by us or by your peers. If you haven’t been invited, ask among your friends and colleagues. (You might wish to log in to see if you already have a profile.)
>
> Stack Overflow grants new invites to users fitting certain criteria of activity on Stack Exchange sites, including reputation. Participate more, ask good questions, and give good answers. You never know what might appear in your inbox.
>
> ### But you might prequalify
>
> Are you active on GitHub or CodePlex? If you are, perhaps we can grant you an invitation immediately.
>
> Try my GitHub...
> Try my CodePlex...

That first line there really should say "Stack Overflow **Careers** profiles" but that's another issue.

I don't know if it actually expires. A lot of companies don't actually expire things. I know the grocery store I worked at gave out fuel discounts that "expired after 14 days" (but they didn't, really).

Comment: If i go to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ and go thru the "create new account" process --> http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/register?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Flogin  It appears I can get an account without invitation?  How is this "invitation-only?"

Comment: @Paul: That's only creating a Stack Exchange account to login with. Once you're logged in, it queries you to request an invite before it lets you create a profile.

Comment: Thank you @animuson.  It would be nice if the careers public-facing page made this more obvious before disappointing someone who went thru the process of getting a StackExchange profile.

Comment: @animuson if there is Try my jsfiddle....